# How can I make my firefox plug-in compatible with future releases

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

There's one feature in my web application which requires a small browser plug-in to work. 99% of the application is ASP.NET + javascript and we have no skills in writing browser plug-ins or any interest in training someone to maintain it so I've used freelancer web sites with great success to get a working firefox plug-in/add-on/extension.

However, the new Firefox rapid release schedule is throwing this whole plan into disarray because every new version of firefox seems to need a new extension. This is not just to do with the em:maxVersion versions in the RDF file; the plugin actually refuses to load, so it seems that  every 6 weeks I will have to commission a freelancer to update the plug-in for the next version of Firefox. From my limited understanding this is because each version of gecko is not compatible with the previous one.

I can't help but think I'm missing something here. For instance, the IE plugin was written in about 2005 for IE6 and we have never needed to touch it; it still works with IE9. Is it really the case that all firefox plug-ins have to be rewritten every 6 weeks, or am I doing something wrong?

The basic function of the plug-in is to use a windows timer to poll shared memory and then traverse the DOM to find a page with a specific javascript function which it then calls.

So my question is, is there any way that I can make a firefox plug-in with a more reasonable lifespan (i.e. year or more), or am I stuck with having to release a new one every time a new version of firefox comes out?

Comment: Does your addon using binary code eg C++? If so then you will definitely run into the issue of needing to re-build every 6 weeks, as Firefox breaks binary compatibility with each release. The way to avoid this is to write your addon entirely using JavaScript and, if you can, going further and ensuring that your add-on is written entirely using the high-level apis provided by Mozilla's Addon SDK. If your addon can work within the SDK's apis, you should not need to update your addon often, if ever to fix a compatibility issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's using C++ at the moment, and it needs to access Windows shared memory so I presume this is not possible using JavaScript.The other thing that concerns me is, even if I issue a new extension for each Firefox release, it means all my users will have to reinstall it every time Firefox updates. This seems like suicidal behaviour on behalf of the Firefox product team.

Comment: As a footnote to this, I have just (via a contractor) re-implemented the function using NPAPI (I think) rather than gecko and XPCOM. The same DLL works with all the versions of firefox we've tried from 3.6 to 10, and also (when repackaged) with Google chrome. So i'm v happy now

Answer (score 2):

The best way to avoid compatibility issues with Firefox addons when using binary code ( c / c++ ) is to use JSCtypes. Here is a recent overview of how this works:

http://blog.mozilla.com/dwitte/2010/03/12/extension-authors-browser-hackers-meet-js-ctypes/

Here is an entry point to the MDN documentation on JSCtypes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes

To avoid this long-term problem with compatibility, I would make a port of your C++ code to jsctypes from xpcom a hard requirement for the contractors you are working with.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting and I didn't know about it.

Comment: feel free to vote up this answer if you feel it addressed your original question :)

Comment: Have done so. Also through some other discussions it seems it's possible to use NSAPI instead of linking with gecko/xulrunner which may address the issue. Apologies if I'm talking nonsense - because I don't really understand what all these words mean :-)

Comment: The issue you will run into with that approach is that you cannot be restartless if you want to load an NSAPI plugin. You *can* be restartless using jsctypes.